# Add help tab in plugins from the toolbox

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

Is it possible to add in QGIS 3 (Python Script) a help tab on the plugins created for the toolbox as it was in QGIS 2?

[image]

Looking in the [API](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingAlgorithm.html) I found the parameters **helpString** that will be deprecated in 3.4, **shortHelpString** which presents the short help on the right side of the main plugin window, and **helpUrl** that creates a button with an external link.

Is there any other parameter that enables the use of a help tab?

I would like to create this tab to make it easier to read the plugin's manual even without internet connection and without opening external files. Being able to display a local HTML would be a great option.